# navigationController.topViewController vs storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I am trying to inject a reference to a property in a uitableviewcontroller from my appdelegate.  The first is successful - I am able to reference xmppStream from my uitableviewcontroller, but the second appears to destroy the reference somewhere and I'm not sure why.

First - ok, xmppStream in uitableviewcontroller is not nil;

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

PhoneNumberTableViewController *myViewController = (PhoneNumberTableViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

[myViewController setXmppStream:[self xmppStream]];
```

Second - gets a reference but is destroyed i.e. in uitableviewcontroller xmppStream is nil?

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

PhoneNumberTableViewController *tv = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserRegistration"];

[tv setXmppStream:[self xmppStream]];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` *instantiates* a viewController, therefore getting a new object which is afterwards discarded since no longer needed / no strong reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what should try is make a property of `PhoneNumberTableViewController` and whenever you need to use is use that variable. like

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

_myViewController = (PhoneNumberTableViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

[myViewController setXmppStream:[self xmppStream]];
```